# Redirect to logout after Error on Request

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I've migrate our application from angular 2 to angular 5 and also migrrate from the deprecated Http to the new HttpClient.

In the old application i had the following Http-Client to redirect from error to a specific page.

```js
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {ConnectionBackend, Http, Request, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Response} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/operator/catch";


@Injectable()
export class HttpService extends Http {

  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, private router: Router) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return super.request(url, options)
      .catch(this.catchErrors());
  }

  private catchErrors() {
    return (res: Response) => {
      if (this.isError(res)) {
        console.log(`Internal server error occured (${res.status} - ${res.statusText})`);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/error');
      } else if (this.isUnauthorized(res)) {
        console.log(`User is not authenticated  - not logged in or the session expired? (${res.status} - ${res.statusText})`);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/logout');
      } else if (this.isForbidden(res)) {
        console.log(`User does not have necessary permissions for the resource (${res.status} - ${res.statusText}): ${res.url}`);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/forbidden');
      }

      return Observable.throw(res);
    };
  }

  private isError(res: Response): boolean {
    return res && res.status === 500;
  }

  private isUnauthorized(res: Response): boolean {
    return res && res.status === 401;
  }

  private isForbidden(res: Response): boolean {
    return res && res.status === 403;
  }

}
```

And now I have refactored this one to a HttpInterceptor

```js
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse} from "@angular/common/http";


@Injectable()
export class HttpService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  private catchErrors() {
    return (res: HttpResponse<any>) => {
      if (this.isError(res)) {
        console.log(`Internal server error occured (${res.status} - ${res.statusText})`);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/error');
      } else if (this.isUnauthorized(res)) {
        console.log(`User is not authenticated  - not logged in or the session expired? (${res.status} - ${res.statusText})`);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/logout');
      } else if (this.isForbidden(res)) {
        console.log(`User does not have necessary permissions for the resource (${res.status} - ${res.statusText}): ${res.url}`);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/forbidden');
      }

      return Observable.throw(res);
    };
  }

  private isError(res: HttpResponse<any>): boolean {
    return res && res.status === 500;
  }

  private isUnauthorized(res: HttpResponse<any>): boolean {
    return res && res.status === 401;
  }

  private isForbidden(res: HttpResponse<any>): boolean {
    return res && res.status === 403;
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).catch(this.catchErrors());
  }

}
```

But now the navigateByUrl has no effect and the site is even accessible.

Has someone any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Try using `return next.handle(req).catch(() => this.catchErrors())` and edit your function so that it returns a failed observable, not a callback.

Answer (score 1):

you can try with this solution

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const started = Date.now();
        /**
         * Handle newly created request with updated header (if given)
         */
        return next.handle(req).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            /**
             * Sucessfull Http Response Time.
             */
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                const elapsed = Date.now() - started;
            }

        }, (err: any) => {
            /**
             * redirect to the error_handler route according to error status or error_code
             */
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                switch (err.status) {
                    case 500:
                        console.log(`Internal server error occured (${err.status} - ${err.statusText})`);
                        this.router.navigateByUrl('/error');
                        break;
                    case 400:
                        console.log(`User is not authenticated  - not logged in or the session expired? (${err.status} - ${err.statusText})`);
                        this.router.navigateByUrl('/logout');
                        break;
                    case 403:
                        console.log(`User does not have necessary permissions for the resource (${err.status} - ${err.statusText}): ${err.url}`);
                        this.router.navigateByUrl('/forbidden');
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. I see the console out but the navigate goes to the target url not the logout-url

Comment: what is the data of err.status

Comment: HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized", url: "http://localhost:9000/ws/rest/countries", ok: false, …}
error:{errNo: 423708275209410, message: "Unauthorized", details: "org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedEx…:61)
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:9000/ws/rest/countries: 401 Unauthorized"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 401
statusText: "Unauthorized"
url: "http://localhost:9000/ws/rest/countries"

Comment: You can add new case for status 401

 case 401:
                        console.log('401 block');
                         break;

Answer (score 1):

You didn't get any console error message?

I would try the following code:

```
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse} from "@angular/common/http";


@Injectable()
export class HttpService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  private catchErrors(httpError) {
      if (this.isError(res)) {
        console.log(`Internal server error occured (${res.status} - ${res.statusText})`);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/error');
      } else if (this.isUnauthorized(res)) {
        console.log(`User is not authenticated  - not logged in or the session expired? (${res.status} - ${res.statusText})`);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/logout');
      } else if (this.isForbidden(res)) {
        console.log(`User does not have necessary permissions for the resource (${res.status} - ${res.statusText}): ${res.url}`);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/forbidden');
      }

      return Observable.throw(res);
  }

  private isError(res: HttpResponse<any>): boolean {
    return res && res.status === 500;
  }

  private isUnauthorized(res: HttpResponse<any>): boolean {
    return res && res.status === 401;
  }

  private isForbidden(res: HttpResponse<any>): boolean {
    return res && res.status === 403;
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).catch(httpError => this.catchErrors(httpError));
  }

}
```

You need to make sure that your `catchErrors`function is binded to your `HttpService` class and do a `Observable.throw` to return a failed `Observable`.

Also check the type of `httpError`, in Angular 6+ I'm using `HttpErrorResponse` but I'm not sure what type is on older versions.

Comment: It also doesn't work as expected. The httpError shows this:
{
  "headers": {
    "normalizedNames": {},
    "lazyUpdate": null
  },
  "status": 401,
  "statusText": "Unauthorized",
  "url": "http://localhost:9000/ws/rest/countries",
  "ok": false,
  "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
  "message": "Http failure response for http://localhost:9000/ws/rest/countries: 401 Unauthorized",
  "error": {
    "errNo": 424875984627997,
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "details": "org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: ..."
  }
}

Comment: When is use window.location.href = 'logout'; instead of navigateByUrl it should work. But I think thats not the proper solution?

Comment: As i see, in your solution the browsers url changes to logout but it's no navigate to them.

Comment: is /logout your absolute url? Mine is like /app/logout, try changing the method to navigate instead navigateByUrl and pass your absolute url path as argument

Comment: The url is handled by the ResourceHandler of Spring MVC and points to the root of the client application. So the url seems to be fine

Comment: Is it possible that my AuthGuard is the problem and not the interceptor?

Comment: It's a though question because you don't have provided more information about this on your question